# Как настроить сертификат CF для поддомена на Oracle Cloud?

Tags: linux, oracle, cloudflare

Есть основной домен и поддомены на определённом IP и на определённом хостинге (dedicated), записями которых управляет Cloudflare.
И есть Oracle Cloud, на котором располагается Zabbix Server и выделен поддомен от основного домена, но естественно с A-записью на другой IP.

Как заставить работать Cloudflare с сертификатом Origin в Oracle Cloud?
Или как сделать https с проксированием через Cloudflare?

Сейчас выдаёт Error 523 - origin is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в предустановленном Oracle Cloud правиле iptables

```
**629 39390 REJECT all -- * * 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited**
```

Удалил и заработало.